# Get number of MPI Communicators in use

Tags: fortran, mpi, intel-mpi

I have a large code, that crashes with the following error:

```
Fatal error in PMPI_Comm_split: Other MPI error, error stack:
PMPI_Comm_split(532)................: MPI_Comm_split(comm=0xc4027cf0, color=0, key=0, new_comm=0x7ffdb50f2bd0) failed
PMPI_Comm_split(508)................: fail failed
MPIR_Comm_split_impl(260)...........: fail failed
MPIR_Get_contextid_sparse_group(676): Too many communicators (0/16384 free on this process; ignore_id=0)
Fatal error in PMPI_Comm_split: Other MPI error, error stack:
PMPI_Comm_split(532)................: MPI_Comm_split(comm=0xc401bcf1, color=1, key=0, new_comm=0x7ffed5aa4fd0) failed
PMPI_Comm_split(508)................: fail failed
MPIR_Comm_split_impl(260)...........: fail failed
MPIR_Get_contextid_sparse_group(676): Too many communicators (0/16384 free on this process; ignore_id=0)
Fatal error in PMPI_Comm_split: Other MPI error, error stack:
PMPI_Comm_split(532)................: MPI_Comm_split(comm=0xc4027ce9, color=0, key=0, new_comm=0x7ffe37e477d0) failed
PMPI_Comm_split(508)................: fail failed
MPIR_Comm_split_impl(260)...........: fail failed
MPIR_Get_contextid_sparse_group(676): Too many communicators (0/16384 free on this process; ignore_id=0)
Fatal error in PMPI_Comm_split: Other MPI error, error stack:
PMPI_Comm_split(532)................: MPI_Comm_split(comm=0xc401bcf1, color=1, key=0, new_comm=0x7ffd511ac4d0) failed
PMPI_Comm_split(508)................: fail failed
MPIR_Comm_split_impl(260)...........: fail failed
MPIR_Get_contextid_sparse_group(676): Too many communicators (0/16384 free on this process; ignore_id=0)
```

It seems that the there is somekind of a MPI communicator leak. MPI seems to be aware of how many communicators are currently being used:

```
Too many communicators (0/16384 free on this process; ignore_id=0)
```

Is there a way to print the number of communicators used by MPI? This way I could narrow down where the communicators are leaking.

Comment: Do you have that many calls to routines making new communicators? Shouldn't it be easier to search around them directly?

Comment: Most of them are created implicitly in scalapack. Printing the number of communicators would help a lot.

Comment: I do not think it is possible. Check your Intel MPI version https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-clusters-and-hpc-technology/topic/634884

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can overide the implementation of `MPI_Comm_split` and `MPI_Comm_free` to manually count the creation and destruction of communicator.

Here is a simple example

Overriding `MPI_Comm_split` and `MPI_Comm_free`

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include "stdio.h"
static int comm_counter=0;
int MPI_Comm_split(MPI_Comm comm, int color, int key, MPI_Comm *newcomm)
{
      int world_rank;
      MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
      comm_counter++;
      printf("%s %i %s %i\n", "MPI_Comm_split ", comm_counter, " from ", world_rank);
      return PMPI_Comm_split(comm, color, key, newcomm);
}

int MPI_Comm_free(MPI_Comm *comm)
{
      int world_rank;
      MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
      comm_counter--;
      printf("%s %i %s %i\n", "PMPI_Comm_free ", comm_counter, " from ", world_rank);
      return PMPI_Comm_free(comm);
}
```

Compile this code to be linked.
In my case I did `mpicc -c comm_split.c -o comm_split.o`

Your code is left untouched. You can use it with no other modifications.
Simple example of main program using `MPI_Comm_split` and `MPI_Comm_free`

**C++ case**

```
#include "mpi.h"
int main()
{
      MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
      // Get the rank and size in the original communicator
      int world_rank, world_size;
      MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
      MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

      int color = world_rank / 4; // Determine color based on row

      // Split the communicator based on the color and use the
      // original rank for ordering
      MPI_Comm row_comm, row_comm2;
      MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, color, world_rank, &row_comm);
      MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, color, world_rank, &row_comm2);

      int row_rank, row_size;
      MPI_Comm_rank(row_comm, &row_rank);
      MPI_Comm_size(row_comm, &row_size);

      printf("WORLD RANK/SIZE: %d/%d \t ROW RANK/SIZE: %d/%d\n",
          world_rank, world_size, row_rank, row_size);

      MPI_Comm_free(&row_comm);
      MPI_Finalize();
}
```

**Fortran case**

```
      program test

      include "mpif.h"

      integer comm_world, group_world, new_comm, new_comm2, ierr
      integer world_rank, world_size;
      integer color


      call MPI_INIT(ierr)

      comm_world = MPI_COMM_WORLD

      call MPI_Comm_rank(comm_world, world_rank, ierr);
      color = world_rank / 4
      call MPI_Comm_split(comm_world, color, world_rank, new_comm, ierr)
      call MPI_Comm_split(comm_world, color, world_rank,
     & new_comm2, ierr)

      call MPI_Comm_free(new_comm, ierr)
      call MPI_Finalize(ierr)
      end program
```

Compile + link with the redefinition of `MPI_Comm_split` and `MPI_Comm_free`

```
mpif77 test.f comm_split.o
mpiCC test.cpp comm_split.o
```

For the **Fortran case** you get something like

```
MPI_Comm_split  1  from  3
MPI_Comm_split  1  from  0
MPI_Comm_split  1  from  1
MPI_Comm_split  1  from  2
MPI_Comm_split  2  from  0
PMPI_Comm_free  1  from  0
MPI_Comm_split  2  from  1
PMPI_Comm_free  1  from  1
MPI_Comm_split  2  from  2
PMPI_Comm_free  1  from  2
MPI_Comm_split  2  from  3
PMPI_Comm_free  1  from  3
```

Which gives you an information about the number of communicators involved in each process.

Comment: @francescalus I have added the fortran case. Hope this makes things clearer.

Comment: Thanks.  I've added some columns to the Fortran source.

Comment: Thanks @francescalus